# Stanford CoreNLP Server binary parse trees

Tags: stanford-nlp, corenlp-server

I use the Stanford CoreNLP Server to generate parse trees By default I get parse trees that are not binary. However, I need binary parse trees to build a Recursive Neural Tensor Network on top. 
Since most of my code is in Python I use the wrapper https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp for the CoreNLP Java library.

What I tried so far:

1. set the -binarize parameter when starting the CorNLP server:

   ```
   $ java -mx4g -cp "/home/jonasrothfuss/Downloads/CoreNLP-master/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -binarize
   ```
2. when making a post "request" that is sent to the CoreNLP Server adding the parse.binaryTree parameter and set it to True

   ```
   properties={
       'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse',
       'outputFormat': 'json',
       'parse.binaryTrees': 'true'
   }
   ```

Nonetheless I still receive not-binary parse trees.

Does anyone know what to do, so that the CoreNLP Server sends back binary parse trees? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for that, same issue here! Thanks